# Use loop to splice string, item is undefined

Tags: ansible, jinja2

below is my task code:

```
- name: Add calculation nodes of different groups to the list
  set_fact: 
    list_of_all_calculate_node: "{{  list_of_all_calculate_node | default([]) + ['random_calculate_host' + ('{{ item }}' | string ) ]  }}"
  loop: "{{ range(1,5) }}"

- name: Print  list_of_all_calculate_node
  debug:
    var: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ list_of_all_calculate_node }}"
```

Error type: fatal

```
TASK [Print  list_of_all_calculate_node]
fatal: [*.*.*.*]: FAILED! => {"msg": "['random_calculate_host2', 'random_calculate_host3', 'random_calculate_host4', 'random_calculate_host{{ item }}']: 'item' is undefined"}
```

The expected output should be:
`['random_calculate_host1','random_calculate_host2', 'random_calculate_host3', 'random_calculate_host4']`

Comment: [moustaches don't stack](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ansible, the curly braces `{{ }}` can't be nested. Fix the syntax, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        l: "{{  l|d([]) + ['random_calculate_host' ~ item] }}"
      loop: "{{ range(1,5) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  l:
  - random_calculate_host1
  - random_calculate_host2
  - random_calculate_host3
  - random_calculate_host4
```

---

You don't have to iterate the *range*, .e.g. the task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        l: "{{ ['random_calculate_host']|product(range(1,5))|map('join')|list }}"
```